# How should I handle nuxt cookies expiration and workflow?

Tags: express, cookies, jwt, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have made an authentication workflow for a project using a Nuxt frontend(universal mode) and an Apollo endpoint as backend.

It is a mix of several examples I found and, with SSR, and since I do not fully anticipate what could go wrong, I wanted to make sure there is no red flag about how I proceed.

On the backend, I use an express middleware to sign JWT auth tokens, check them, and return them in the Authorization header. Here is the middleware:

```js
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { AuthenticationError } from 'apollo-server-express';

export const getToken = payload => {
    return jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SEED, { expiresIn: process.env.EXPTOKEN });
}
export const checkToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const rawToken = req.headers["authorization"]
    if (rawToken) {
        try {
            const token = rawToken.substring(7)
            // Verify that the token is validated
            const { user, role } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SEED);

            const newToken = getToken({ user, role });

            req.user = user;
            req.role = role;
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            res.set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "authorization");
            res.set("authorization", newToken);

        } catch (error) {
            if (error.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
                res.set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "authorization");
                res.set("authorization", false);
            }
            console.log("invalid token", error);
            return new AuthenticationError
            // Invalid Token
        }
    }

    next();
}
```

Since there is a [Nuxt-Apollo module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module), I used its methods [onLogin, onLogout and getToken](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module#authentication) to store the JWT string in a cookie. As I understand it, SSR apps don't have the serverside local storage matching the client so they have to use cookies. Correct?

Here is my nuxt middleware where I check the users credentials before allowing them to visit an auth route. Is is quite messy but it gets the job done, except for the commented part.

```js
export default function ({ app, route, error, redirect }) {
  const hasToken = !!app.$apolloHelpers.getToken()

  // this part does not work
  /*   const tokenExpireDateTime = app.$cookies.nodeCookie.parse('cookie-name', 'expires')
    if (hasToken && tokenExpireDateTime < 0) {
      error({ statusCode: 403, message: 'Permission denied', description: 'Sorry, you are forbidden from accessing this page.' })
      app.$apolloHelpers.onLogout()
      return redirect('/login')
    }
   */
  if (!hasToken) {
    if (route.name === 'welcome-key') {
      // enrollment link route
    } else {
      if (route.name === 'home') {
        error({ errorCode: 403, message: 'You are not allowed to see this' })

        return redirect('/showcase')
      }
      if (!['login', 'forgot_password', 'reset_password-key'].includes(route.name)) {
        error({ errorCode: 403, message: 'You are not allowed to see this' })

        return redirect('/login')
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (['login', 'forgot_password', 'reset_password-key'].includes(route.name)) {

      redirect('/')
    }
  }
}
```

I have one issue and several points of confusion.

My issue is that I can't get the cookie `expires` value to redirect in the above nuxt middlware if it is necessary to login again because the JWT is expired. I used the piece of code mentioned [in this issue](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/issues/302) as reference.

With this issue, my confusion is about:

- The expires date on the cookie is set by the Nuxt-Apollo module, I expect, and I have to make it match the duration set on server (i.e. `process.env.EXPTOKEN` in the server middleware mentioned above), correct?
- That expiration time alone can easily be tempered with and the real security is the lack of a valid token in headers when a request is handled by my server middleware. Its use is for client-side detection and redirect of an expired token/cookie, and serverside prefetch of user related data during SSR. Right?
- The new token emitted by my express backend middleware is not taken into account in my frontend: it is not updating the cookie stored JWT and `expires` value client side. I mean that I can see the autorization header JWT string being updated in the response, but the cookie isn't. The following request still use the first JWT string. Am I supposed to update it at each roundtrip? What am I missing with the approach of the express middleware (that, as you can guess, I didn't write)

Please help me understand better this workflow and how I could improve it. It tried to avoid as much as possible to make this question too broad, but if I can narrow it down more, feel free to suggest an edit.